# Getting a value from a Json Response which has " " around parameters

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse the response from the server something like this

```
public class TestClass {
public class TaskResponse {

        private String id;
        private List<String> links;
        public String getId(){

            return id;

            }  
      }

public static void main(String args[]){


       String response = "{
 "task": {
  "id": 10, 
  "links": [
   {
    "href": "http://localhost:9000/v1/115e4ad38aef463e8f99991baad1f809/os-hosts/svs144/onboard/10"
   }
  ]
 }
}";

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(response).getAsJsonObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
TaskResponse tskResponse = gson.fromJson(response, TaskResponse.class);
String taskId = tskResponse.getId();
System.out.println("The task Id is "+taskId);

}

}
```

In what I am originally doing I get the task id as null but in this code also which I have written above to try and understand the problem, Eclipse is giving error in the string response, it does not recognize it is a proper string.
Please see to it that I can't change the response string as it is coming from server. Any help of any kind or any links to sort out the error will be highly appreciated.
Thanx in Advance.

Comment: If you're declaring a String in Java for testing purposes, you'll need to escape the double quotes inside the string using the backslach, so `\"`.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with Gson (I've never had any occasion to work with JSON in Java), but I don't see how it's supposed to know what to do with the `task` property declared in your response.

Comment: Wouldn't using `'` in the JSON be more convenient?

Comment: @mabi: The response is from a server. I can't change that.
Anthony :Which task property ??

Comment: @MAD_ABOUT_JAVA `'` and `"` are equivalent, so you can use `'` in your test code to simplify.

Comment: @mabi : That thing worked by replacing " in \" in the test code. Now I am getting the task id as null, I need to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson will try to match the JSON-string to your class' structure.

Since your JSON starts with `task : { ... }` it will try to find a property `task` on the class `TaskResponse`. Since there's no such field, it won't set anything on your instance.

So either convert it more generally (e.g. using `Map.class` as the target) or add the `task` property to a wrapper class:

```
class TaskResponse {
    private Task task;
}

class Task {
    private Long id;
    private List<Link> links;
}

class Link {
    String href;
}
```

There's also a third option detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12004742/785663).

Answer (score 1):

inside the string " can not directly be use

u need to escape it by replacing it to \"

" ===> \"

```
String response = "{
 \"task\": {
  \"id\": 10, 
  \"links\": [
   {
    \"href\": \"http://`localhost`:9000/v1/115e4ad38aef463e8f99991baad1f809/os-hosts/svs144/onboard/10\"
   }
  ]
 }
}";
```

Comment: So I need to iterate through the whole string that I am getting from server and replace " with \" , is that what you are trying to say ??

Comment: if you are passing value inside your string statically , then yes you have to escape all " character

Comment: :Not talking about this SSCCE, in what I am originally doing the response is coming from a server and there it does not give error in the string but it simply in the end gives me the task id as null.

Comment: well that is plain parsing mistake , you need to get JSON object , get element by its id name , then print its value

Comment: String taskId = tskResponse.getId();
I am not able to get the mistake, can you please point me to what mistake I am doing in parsing ??

Comment: right now i cant download your gson jar , will respond in a few hours after finishing my office hours :( :( :( , inconvenience regretted

Comment: No problem, thanx for the help , I would check after some time.