# Gson - Json list to Java List<Object>

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having some problems with a conversion of a Json object list to a Java List. I'm using the GSon to do it.
**I have the following Json list:**

```
{"player":
    [
    {"id":"1","age":"25","name":"Neuer"},
    {"id":"2","age":"26","name":"Cristiano Ronaldo"},
    {"id":"3","age":"24","name":"Lionel Messi"}
    ]
}
```

**And I have the following Java Object:**

```
public class PlayerDTO implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**In my Java class I'm doing:**

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PlayerDTO>>(){}.getType();
List<PlayerDTO> players = gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
```

But, when the Gson tries to convert the Json list I receive the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:691)
at br.com.test.TesteGson.main(TesteGson.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
... 4 more
```

I understand that it happens because the Gson was expecting the Json without the ***"player"*** on the beginning of the Json String. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: My recommendation is to create a `PlayerCollection` (?) type which contains an appropriate players list property..

Comment: Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004338/skip-root-element-while-deserializing-json - but these methods seem crufty

Comment: It seems gson now comes with [streaming api](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) using which you may be able to avoid extra parsing.

Comment: So you're trying to skip the initial 'player' object and just get the list?

Comment: No, I wanna know if I'm doing something wrong, because I believe that the Gson is able to convert this Json String in a Java List<Object>

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this issue is to create a Players class to serve as a collection for your players.

Here is the `Players` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class Players {

@Expose
private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

public List<Player> getPlayer() {
return player;
}

public void setPlayer(List<Player> player) {
this.player = player;
}

}
```

The `Player` class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class Player {

@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String age;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: Well, I believe that this is not the best solution. Hoping anyone else gives me another solution.