# How to access an array within json?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

Using gson how would you access values within the leagueTable array in this json?

Here is the json structure and is stored as a String called "dataRead"

```
{
   "data":{
      "fixtures":[
         {
         }
      ],
    "leagueTable":[
         {
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My gson code looks like this and the printline is to access an object within the array

```
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(dataRead, Data.class);
System.out.println(data.leagueTable[0].team);
```

My Data class looks like this and matches what is in the json

```
public class Data {
    LeagueTable[] leagueTable;

    public Data(LeagueTable[] leagueTable) {
        this.leagueTable = leagueTable;
    }

    public static class LeagueTable {
        String team;
        int played, gamesWon, gamesDraw, gameLost, goalsFor, goalsAgainst, goalsDifference, points;

        public LeagueTable(String team, int played, int gamesWon, int gamesDraw, int gameLost, int goalsFor,
                int goalsAgainst, int goalsDifference, int points) {
            this.team = team;
            this.played = played;
            this.gamesWon = gamesWon;
            this.gamesDraw = gamesDraw;
            this.gameLost = gameLost;
            this.goalsFor = goalsFor;
            this.goalsAgainst = goalsAgainst;
            this.goalsDifference = goalsDifference;
            this.points = points;
        }

    }
}
```

I expect a String of the first team in the leagueTable array but I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004338/skip-root-element-while-deserializing-json

Comment: Where does the stacktrace say the NPE is happening if you split out the System.out.println line into three separate lines? E.g. line 1 is `data`, line 2 is `.leagueTable[0]`, line 3 is `.team`? That will tell you which part of the object is not getting deserialized.

Comment: @spork I put data in the printline and it gave me:
    dawfl.Data@5056dfcb   (dawfl being my package)
System.out.println(data.leagueTable[0]);
gives me the NPE

Comment: @jmcveigh15 You may need a default constructor in LeagueTable. Would you add one and see if that clears up the NPE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data struture represented by `Data` is not fitting your json struture. Therefore, Gson only create new instance of type `Data`, but does not fill it with members' valuse.
Try this implementation:

```
public class MyObject {

    private Data data;

    public static class Data {

       private FixturesStrutue[] fixtures;
       private LeagueTable[] leagueTable;

       public static class LeagueTable {
           String team;
           int played, gamesWon, gamesDraw, gameLost, goalsFor, goalsAgainst, 
                   goalsDifference, points;

       }

       public static class FixturesStrutue {
           String member1;
           int member2;

       }
   }
}
```

Now, use Gson:

```
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(dataRead, MyObject.class);
System.out.println(data.leagueTable[0].team);
```

The last line (`data.leagueTable[0].team`) will still throw NPE because you have no elements in the `leagueTable` array in the json. Add it at least one element and it will be fine.

Gson will inject all the properties from the json to the corresponding members in the class **by name**. If you want the member and the property to be with different names, read about [SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).